# Curve to Mesh vs Instance on Points

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, curve-modifier

I want to make a lathe node that takes a curve and rotates it around the z-axis using either Curve to Mesh or Instance on Points. The attached node graph does mostly what I want but I have to fiddle with Align Euler to Vector and even add another Transform Geometry to rotate the curve seperately just for Curve to Mesh.

[image: blender question]

How can I get rid of the highlighted Transform Geometry node and still get the same shape? I.e. how can I feed the same curve into both Curve to Mesh and Instance on Points and get identical results?

Eventually I'd like to be able to choose the axis to rotate the curve around (and maybe even specify an arbitrary axis). I'd also like Set Curve Tilt (muted in my example) to work for both Curve to Mesh and Instance on Points.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Sure. I apologize it's so cluttered. I'm in the middle of fiddling with the setup for the other axes to try to reason out a generalized relationship between Curve to Mesh and Instance on Points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this kind of setting:

[image]

You need to shift the curve by its starting position (set position with offset, so that first point is on its origin because instance on points uses this origin), and by construction know that the curve profile is along the X axis (align X to the circle normal).

---

You can also make this kind of things this way:

[image]

Resample the curve in order to place the curve circle profile at the end.

Sample the positions in order to have X as the depth, which is the radius.

Place the points at the center (X=0 and keep Y and Z).

Convert to mesh.